# A finite intersection of open sets is open

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I have to prove that a finite intersection of open sets is open. My idea is to do a proof by contradiction. The definition of an open set is as follows:

A subset $U \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is open if for every point $x \in U$, there exists $ r > 0$ such that the open ball $B_r(x)$ is contained in U.

Is my starting point valid?

Let $A_1, A_2 ... A_k$ open sets and let $x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^{k} A_i$. Suppose the intersection is not open and then there must be an $x\in  \bigcap_{i=1}^{k} A_i$ such that given any $\epsilon>0,\ B_{\epsilon}(x)\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} A_i^c$.  From here I could look for a particular $\epsilon$ to find a contradiction.

Comment: No, if $\bigcap_{i=1}^kA_i$ is not open, there is an $x\in\bigcap_{i=1}^kA_i$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$, $B_\epsilon(x)\nsubseteq\bigcap_{i=1}^kA_i$. This is *not* the same as saying that $B_\epsilon(x)\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i^c$; rather, it says that $B_\epsilon(x)\cap\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i^c\ne\varnothing$. You should instead try to prove the result by induction on $k$.

Comment: **Hint:** Draw a finite number of disks (4 or 5) all centered about the same point on a piece of paper. Notice that the smallest disk is contained in each of the other disks, and so the smallest disk will be contained in any superset of any of the disks . . . Now figure out how this is relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You starting point is valid. The continuation is not correct since the negation of $B \subset A $ is not $B \subset A^c$.

Instead you could argue in a direct way, like this: for each $x$ in the intersection, you have $x \in A_i$ for each $i$.

Thus for each $i$ you have an $r_i > 0$ such that $B_{r_i}(x)\subset A_i$. 
Then show that for $r $ the smallest of all the $r_i$ you have $B_r(x)$ is a subset of the intersection. (Note that you use that the collection is finite when you say there is a smallest of the $r_i$. In the infinite case you'd need a infimum and this may be $0$ and thus would not help.)

---

Maybe let me add that if you are set on doing it via a contradiction, then you can do so too, but you'd need the correct negation, that is (as noted in a comment) for all $r>0$ you have $B_r(x) \cap \bigcup_i A_i^c \neq \emptyset$. From this you can argue that there is some $i$ such that $B_r(x) \cap  A_i^c \neq \emptyset$ for all $r$, contradicting the assumption that $A_i$ is open. (Yet note that there is some additional argument to be made, since a priori there is no reason that the same $i$ works for all $r$; there you need that you only have finitely many sets.)